# What is Trident State in Storm?

Tags: apache-storm, trident

I am new to Trident in Storm. I am breaking my head over TridentState. As far as my understanding trident maintains the state (i.e metadata) for each batch (whether all the tuples in a batch are completely processed by maintaining a Transaction id in the Database) and i am not entirely sure what the following statement does

```
TridentState urlToTweeters =
   topology.newStaticState(getUrlToTweetersState());
```

Can anyone explain what actually happens when we define the above code?

Comment: Can you define "Trident" in this context?  There are multiple things called Trident.

Comment: The context is "Storm": https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Documentation#trident

Answer (score 10):

I hope it's never too late to answer, at least somebody else might find my answer useful :)

So, `topology.newStaticState()` is a Trident's abstraction of a queryable data storage. A parameter for `newStaticState()` should be an implementation - based on the method's contract - of `storm.trident.state.StateFactory`. The factory, in turn, should implement `makeState()` method returning an instance of `storm.trident.state.State`. However if you plan to query your state, you should return an istance of `storm.trident.state.map.ReadOnlyMapState` instead, since plain `storm.trident.state.State` doesn't have methods for querying an actual data source (you'll actually get a class cast exception if you try to use anything but `ReadOnlyMapState`).

So, let's give it a try!

A dummy state implementation:

```
public static class ExampleStaticState implements ReadOnlyMapState<String> {

    private final Map<String, String> dataSourceStub;

    public ExampleStaticState() {
        dataSourceStub = new HashMap<>();
        dataSourceStub.put("tuple-00", "Trident");
        dataSourceStub.put("tuple-01", "definitely");
        dataSourceStub.put("tuple-02", "lacks");
        dataSourceStub.put("tuple-03", "documentation");
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> multiGet(List<List<Object>> keys) {

        System.out.println("DEBUG: MultiGet, keys is " + keys);

        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

        for (List<Object> inputTuple : keys) {
            result.add(dataSourceStub.get(inputTuple.get(0)));
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void beginCommit(Long txid) {
        // never gets executed...
        System.out.println("DEBUG: Begin commit, txid=" + txid);
    }

    @Override
    public void commit(Long txid) {
        // never gets executed...
        System.out.println("DEBUG: Commit, txid=" + txid);
    }
}
```

A factory:

```
public static class ExampleStaticStateFactory implements StateFactory {
    @Override
    public State makeState(Map conf, IMetricsContext metrics, int partitionIndex, int numPartitions) {
        return new ExampleStaticState();
    }
}
```

A simple `psvm` (aka `public static void main`):

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    TridentTopology tridentTopology = new TridentTopology();
    FeederBatchSpout spout = new FeederBatchSpout(Arrays.asList(new String[]{
            "foo"
    }));
    TridentState state = tridentTopology.newStaticState(new ExampleStaticStateFactory());
    tridentTopology
            .newStream("spout", spout)
            .stateQuery(state, new Fields("foo"), new MapGet(), new Fields("bar"))
            .each(new Fields("foo", "bar"), new Debug())
            ;

    Config conf = new Config();
    conf.setNumWorkers(6);

    LocalCluster localCluster = new LocalCluster();
    localCluster.submitTopology("tridentTopology", conf, tridentTopology.build());

    spout.feed(Arrays.asList(new Values[]{
            new Values("tuple-00"),
            new Values("tuple-01"),
            new Values("tuple-02"),
            new Values("tuple-03")
    }));

    localCluster.shutdown();
}
```

And, finally, the output:

```
DEBUG: MultiGet, keys is [[tuple-00], [tuple-01], [tuple-02], [tuple-03]]
DEBUG: [tuple-00, Trident]
DEBUG: [tuple-01, definitely]
DEBUG: [tuple-02, lacks]
DEBUG: [tuple-03, documentation]
```

You see, stateQuery() gets values from an input batch and maps them to the values found in the 'data storage'.

Diving a bit deeper, you can take a look at the source of `MapGet` class (the guy whose instance is used for querying inside the topology) and find the following there:

```
public class MapGet extends BaseQueryFunction<ReadOnlyMapState, Object> {
    @Override
    public List<Object> batchRetrieve(ReadOnlyMapState map, List<TridentTuple> keys) {
        return map.multiGet((List) keys);
    }    

    @Override
    public void execute(TridentTuple tuple, Object result, TridentCollector collector) {
        collector.emit(new Values(result));
    }    
}
```

So under the hood it simply calls `multiGet()` method of your `ReadOnlyMapState` implementation and then emits values found in the data storage, adding them to the already existing tuple. You can (although it might not be the best thing to do) create your own implementation of `BaseQueryFunction<ReadOnlyMapState, Object>` doing something more complicated.

Comment: can you help on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35445165/total-number-of-non-repeated-words-in-each-tweet

Answer (score 0):

There's good documentation on Trident state [on the storm wiki](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Trident-state). Simple answer to your question is that `urlToTweeters` is a state object that can be queried from. I'm assuming the statement above is from the [trident tutorial](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Trident-tutorial), reproduced below:

```
TridentState urlToTweeters = topology.newStaticState(getUrlToTweetersState());
TridentState tweetersToFollowers = topology.newStaticState(getTweeterToFollowersState());
topology.newDRPCStream("reach")
  .stateQuery(urlToTweeters, new Fields("args"), new MapGet(), new Fields("tweeters")).each(new Fields("tweeters"), new ExpandList(), new Fields("tweeter"))
  /* At this point we have the tweeters for each url passed in args */
  .shuffle()        
  .stateQuery(tweetersToFollowers, new Fields("tweeter"), new MapGet(), new Fields("followers"))
  .parallelismHint(200)
  .each(new Fields("followers"), new ExpandList(), new Fields("follower"))
  .groupBy(new Fields("follower"))
  .aggregate(new One(), new Fields("one"))
  .parallelismHint(20)
  .aggregate(new Count(), new Fields("reach"));
```

In this example, `urlToTweeters` would store a mapping of URLs to Tweeters, and the DRPC `reach` query defined on the next line (that takes in URLs as its arguments) would ultimately yield the reach. But on the way (marked with a comment inline) you would see a stream of the tweeters of each url, i.e., the result of a query on `urlToTweeters`.

Comment: can you help on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35445165/total-number-of-non-repeated-words-in-each-tweet