# Total number of non repeated words in each tweet

Tags: java, twitter, apache-storm, trident

I'm new to java and Trident , I imported project for getting tweets but i want to get something How this code get more than one tweet as i got form the code that `tuple.getValue(0);`   means first tweet only ?!

Problem with me to get all tweets in hashset or hashmap to get total number of distnictive words in each tweet

```
public void execute(TridentTuple tuple, TridentCollector collector) {
```

this method is used to execute equations on tweet

```
public Values getValues(Tweet tweet, String[] words){
 }
```

This code got first tweet then get body of it ,converting it to array of string , i know what i need to solve but couldn't write it well

My Think : 
Make for loop like

```
for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
 Tweet tweet = (Tweet) tuple.getValue(i);   
}
```

Comment: Are you aware of the basic properties of a `Set`? Hint: a `Set` does not allow duplicates. Extrapolate this to your need.

Comment: thanks for replying , no i didn't know that , but excuse me do you know about trident , i think i need to write like that  str = br.readLine() will give me the line.
str.split(" ") will give me the array of strings then iterate through each elements of array and store it inhashset but problem is to loop in tweets !

Comment: Does it mean that you want to obtain a list of unique words across several tweets? Sorry, your problem is unclear.

Comment: i need to obtain total number of unique words in each tweet , edited post with examples

Comment: It is still very unclear. Your example code does not show at all that you collect the number of words of a tweet anywhere.

Comment: what about this lines  Tweet tweet = (Tweet) tuple.getValue(0);        
    String tweetBody = tweet.getBody();
    String words[] = tweetBody.toLowerCase().split(regex); ? i have another method i wrote it's declaration above in the post if you need its details i will

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103665/discussion-between-user1-and-fge).

Answer (score 0):

1. For each tweet:

   - For each word in tweet:

     - Try adding each word to a set.
       If the word already exists in the set, remove it from the set.
   - count size of set containing words for that tweet.

Comment: thanks for replying i get this well but problem with me is how to loop in tweets to get each tweet as i tried this for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
 Tweet tweet = (Tweet) tuple.getValue(i);   
} but didn't work

Comment: Use tuple.getValues(), which returns a list of objects. Iterate over that list instead of trying to retrieve each tweet separately.

Comment: thanks , do you mean like that for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
       {
       Object o= tuple.getValue(i); } but after that i need to cast each object to tweet like Tweet tweet = (Tweet) tuple.getValue(i) how can i write it ?

Comment: List tweetList = tuple.getvalues();

Comment: thanks but didn't work as tuple return object of tweet type i couldn't write it well like above method Tweet tweet = (Tweet) tuple.getValue(0)

Comment: after getting the entire list, iterate over it with a for each loop an cast it to a tweet as you go. ie `for(Object t : tweetList){ //tweet = (Tweet) t }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103662/discussion-between-user1-and-p1g1n).

Comment: sorry for late reply ,i'll try it later and get back to you

Answer (score -1):

The "problem" is a miss-match between "get the count of distinct words over all tweets" and Strom as a stream processor. The query you want to answer can only be computed on a finite set of Tweets. However, in stream processing you process an potential infinite stream of input data.

If you have a finite set of Tweets, you might want to use a batch processing framework such as Flink, Spark, or MapReduce. If you indeed have an infinite number of Tweets, you must rephrase your question...

As you mentioned already, you actually want to "loop over all Tweets". As you so stream processing, there is no such concept. You have an infinite number of input tuples, and Storm applies `execute()` on each of those (ie, you can think of it as if Storm "loops over the input" automatically -- even in "looping" is not the correct term for it). As your computation is "over all Tweets" you would need to maintain a **state** in your Bolt code, such that you can update this state for each Tweet. The simples form of a state in Storm would be member variable in your Bolt class.

```java
public class MyBolt implements ??? {
    // this is your "state" variable
    private final Set<String> allWords = new HashSet<String>();

    public void execute(TridentTuple tuple, TridentCollector collector) {
        Tweet tweet = (Tweet)tuple.getValue(0);        
        String tweetBody = tweet.getBody();
        String words[] = tweetBody.toLowerCase().split(regex);
        for(String w : words) {
            // as allWords is a set, you cannot add the same word twice
            // the second "add" call on the same word will just be ignored
           // thus, allWords will contain each word exactly once
            this.allWords.add(w);
        }
    }
}
```

Right now, this code does not emit anything, because it is unclear what you actually want to emit? As in stream processing, there is no end, you cannot say "emit the final count of words, contained in `allWords`". What you could do, it to emit the **current count** after each update... For this, add `collector.emit(new Values(this.allWords.size()));` at the end of `execute()`.

Furthermore, I want to add, that the presented solution only works correctly, if no parallelism is applied to `MyBolt` -- otherwise, the different sets over the instances might contain the same word. To resolve this, it would be required to tokenize each Tweet into its words in a stateless Bolt and feet this streams of words into an adopted `MyBolt` that uses an internal `Set` as state. The input data for `MyBolt` must also receive the data via `fieldsGrouping` to ensure distinct sets of words on each instance.

Comment: thanks for great answer , i have 50000 tweets only not infinite and i used debug to know how can the code will get tweets and i got it by method execute after implemented it with getvalues method then emitted after that transfered to next tweet and so on .. there is another method used for calculation i will post it in the post now

Comment: Why do you use Storm if you want to do batch processing? I would strongly recommend to use a batch system like Flink, Spark, MapReduce... I cannot follow the rest of your comment though.

Comment: this project using trident not actually storm , i posted the methed which he calculated number of occuerences of terms in the collection , what i need is to modify this equation only so i think i will not need to change more in code , Am i or i'm wrong ?

Comment: Trident is "just" an API abstraction on top of Storm which is the underlying execution engine; thus, it is still stream processing and seems not to fit your batch use case. -- I can't provide any other help here.